# Nginx proxy_pass entire request to remote server

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I want to have phpMyAdmin running under another port and pass all requests that go to `/pma/` to `127.0.0.1:8081`

Thats my Nginx config

```
server {
   listen 80;
   ...
   location /pma/ {
       proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
       proxy_redirect    off;
       proxy_set_header  Host $host;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
       ...
   }
}
```

Now when I request `http://domain.com/pma/phpinfo.php` `location ~ \.php$` takes over the control and I get a 404. Is it possible to always pass the request to `http://127.0.0.1:8081` when its to `/pma/`?

Comment: This is a total guess, but have you tried taking the trailing slash off the `location /pma/` line?  So it looks like `location /pma` without trailing slash?

Comment: @DanFarrell yes I did. No success :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
location ^~ /pma/ {
    ...
}
```

`^~` will prevent nginx to look for regexp locations.